# Custom hooks redirect loop

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a custom hook for excluding some paths from url and pushing them to a 404 page.
Also i'm using next js dynamic routing  hence the [tv].

When i enter a url witch is whitelisted in the whiteList array i just get looped in a redirect loop.

Once i remove the `not(!)` operator from the conditional statement it works for any url that is not included in the array, which confuses me.

Is there something wrong with the logic or am i missing something?

```js
const whiteList = ['television1', 'television2', 'television3'];
export const useWhiteListParams = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { tv } = router.query;
  useEffect(() => {
      if(!whiteList.includes(tv)) {
          router.push('/404');
      }
  }, [tv])

}
```

Thank you

Comment: You must check how /404 page is rendered and make sure to use useWhiteListParams only in pages that render with tv param

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri you are saving me on this project :) So i cant use this hook in components only in pages even if the component renders the tv param?

Comment: You can. its just that /404 page must not use it, otherwise it will go into a loop

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It still goes in to a loop even thou the /404 page renders only a h2 element, no components.